# How do I retrieve ATPCO itineraries from Bargain Finder Max REST api as I am only able to retrieve NDC results currently?

Tags: sabre

I am having a problem trying to use the Bargain Finder Max REST api (v4) to retrieve mixed NDC and ATPCO content, I can get NDC content returned with my requests but if I disable NDC as a data source and just have ATPCO enabled then I get errors back but no detail about what is wrong with my request. Can someone please help with what I am missing from my request or doing wrong.

```
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "AvailableFlightsOnly": true,
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2024-05-17T08:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR",
                    "LocationType": "A"
                },
                "Fixed": false,
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "CDG",
                    "LocationType": "A"
                }
            }
        ],
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "FixedPCC": false,
                    "PseudoCityCode": "<PCC>",
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "CompanyName": {
                            "Code": "TN"
                        },
                        "ID": "1",
                        "Type": "AG"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "100ITINS"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelPreferences": {
            "CabinPref": [
                {
                    "Cabin": "Economy",
                    "PreferLevel": "Only"
                }
            ],
            "ETicketDesired": false,
            "Hybrid": true,
            "LookForAlternatives": true,
            "MaxStopsQuantity": 10,
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "DataSources": {
                    "ATPCO": "Enable",
                    "LCC": "Disable",
                    "NDC": "Disable"
                },
                "TripType": {
                    "Value": "OneWay"
                }
            },
            "ValidInterlineTicket": false
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "PriceRequestInformation": {
                "NegotiatedFaresOnly": false,
                "ProcessThruFaresOnly": false,
                "PurchaseDate": "0001-01-01",
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "Priority": {
                        "DirectFlights": {
                            "Priority": 2
                        },
                        "Price": {
                            "Priority": 1
                        },
                        "Time": {
                            "Priority": 3
                        },
                        "Vendor": {
                            "Priority": 4
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Version": "V4"
    }
}
```

The response that I get back from the api is:

```
{
    "groupedItineraryResponse": {
        "version": "6.7.2",
        "messages": [
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "SERVER",
                "code": "GCA14-ISELL-TN-00-2023-10-00-HRVH",
                "text": "27131"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "WORKERTHREAD",
                "code": "TRANSACTIONID",
                "text": "7278759797149975752"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "DRE",
                "code": "RULEID",
                "text": "21763"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Info",
                "type": "DEFAULT",
                "code": "RULEID",
                "text": "25238"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "HPIS",
                "code": "PROCESS",
                "text": "INVALID REQUEST"
            },
            {
                "severity": "Error",
                "type": "ERR",
                "code": "ERR",
                "text": "Error during Processing"
            }
        ],
        "statistics": {
            "itineraryCount": 0
        }
    }
}
```